# Convert VTK into JSON with a script

Tags: python, json, blender, vtk

I need to convert a vtk file into json file in the back-end of a server (e.g subprocess). Therefore, I would like to create a script (e.g. python) I can call and run from remote. Are there any tutorial  for that ? 
Thank you !

Regards

Comment: VTK description data should the minimum to post ...

Comment: This ( https://github.com/cwant/VTKBlender ) must be "inside Blender module".  It has a clear readme and sample file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I have a problem when I run the python script via blender: blender --background --python VTKBlender.py, then I receive the error: ImportError: No module named 'vtk'. But when I run the script outside blender (e.g. python VTKBlender.py) I have no problem with vtk library. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Start by [running blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) from your script/process with the background mode argument `--background`. You can follow that with a python script with the `--python <script.py>` argument. You may find [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6817/935) on how to pass arguments to a script interesting.

```
blender --background --python export_to_json.py
```

You already know where to get the info for importing VTK. If you don't know, the three.js project has a [blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender) that uses JSON.

The script you make would use the following two commands to do the import and export -

```
VTKBlender.PolyDataMapperToBlender.convert(pmapper, me=None)
bpy.ops.export.three(filepath=outfile)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I believe it is the right direction. I have a problem when I run the python script via blender:
blender --background --python VTKBlender.py, then
I receive the error: ImportError: No module named 'vtk'.
But when I run the script outside blender (e.g. python VTKBlender.py) I have no problem with vtk library. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Blender uses it's own install of python. Check the module is installed into blenders python or the path is added to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.path) or `PYTHONPATH` environment variable so it can be found. You can find several questions about [installing third party modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=install+modules) for blender.